# Firefox fails to load pages, waits for Facebook resources

Tags: firefox, facebook, firebug

Lately I've been having problems loading pages in Firefox (40.0.3) on a particular website (http://www.idea.int/). I haven't noticed the problem on other websites but not sure if it actually only happens on this site. The problem doesn't happen on every page load, but about half of them, seemingly at random. The problem is the same on two different machines on two different networks (home and office). Firefox loads most of the page contents, but then gets stuck, with "Read s-static.ak.facebook.com" in the status bar. If I inspect the "Net" tab in Firebug, I see no requests at all to that domain, but a request for http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js that never finishes.

Interestingly, if I inspect the contents of that sdk.js (which loads fine if I just open it in a separate tab), I see some config setting `"cdn_https":"s-static.ak.facebook.com"`, which indicates sdk.js and s-static.ak.facebook.com are in fact related somehow.

The problem seems to only occur in Firefox. It might be worth noting that the site is not an HTTPS site, so I'm not sure why Facebook's "cdn_https" would come into play at all (there is also a reference to "cdn_http":"static.ak.facebook.com" inside sdk.js but I never see FF waiting for that domain).

I'm out of ideas for how to troubleshoot this further and I don't seem to understand the mechanisms involved, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the website you are trying to load? Does it load with other browsers? Have you tried disabling your firefox extensions? With a new profile? From another machine on your local network?

Comment: Sorry, edited question to include the URL now. Also added info about the problem being the same on two different machines on two different networks. I haven't tried disabling extensions yet, which I obviously should. Will try that now and add my findings to the question.

Comment: Given that the website has 300 css errors, and 63 html errors/warnings I'm surprised it works at all. It loads fine for me using Firefox 40.0.3 by the way (apart from the page layout being horridly broken). See http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?profile=css3&warning=0&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.idea.int%2F, and https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showoutline=yes&useragent=Validator.nu%2FLV+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.idea.int%2F for the errors.

Comment: Thanks for checking @DavidPostill. I'll appear like an idiot now, but suddenly the problem has stopped occurring. I created a new, clean profile and everything worked fine. I switched back to the normal profile and things were still fine and I couldn't make the problem, which I've had for at least two weeks, to come back again. Even on my other machine I can't make it happen. I'm sure it will come back again as soon as I remove this question, so I guess I'll leave it open for a while longer.